# Java9 for Solaris X64

Tags: oracle, solaris, java-9

Java 9 was released yesterday and I was eager to give it a spin through a test suite which happens to be on a Solaris x64 server. However, I cannot figure out how to download Java9 (JRE) for Solaris X64.
Here's what it looks like for Java 9:

[image: Java 9 downloads]

Here's what it looks like for Java 8:
[image: Java 8 downloads]

According to [this](http://jdk.java.net/9/supported), Solaris x64 is a *supported* platform. But according to [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk9certconfig-3761018.html), Solaris x64 is no longer a *certified* platform for Oracle Java. (the equivalent list for Java 8 is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html))

I don't understand where this leaves me.

Questions:

- Is Oracle officially dropping support for Solaris x64?  Has anything been communicated on this topic?
- I can actually download a perfect copy of Java 9 for Solaris x64 from Oracle's website, just by replacing `sparcv9` with `x64` in the URL. Is that safe to use for production purpose ? Would there be legal issues in using it?

### UPDATE Jan 2019

Overview of various JDK distributions in relation to Solaris X64:

- [Liberica, by BellSoft](https://www.bell-sw.com/java.html) have support for Solaris X64 (and Solaris SPARC for that matter)
- [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) seem to be dropping support for Solaris. For JDK8 they did in fact support Solaris but only on SPARC, not on Intel (odd choice). For later versions of the JDK there's no Solaris mentioned at all.
- [Zulu, by Azul](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/) seem to focus exclusively on Windows, Mac OSX and Linux, but with a note to contact them if you are interested in Solaris.
- [Amazon Corretto](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/) seem to focus exclusively on Windows, Mac OSX and Linux.

Comment: Well the link says *No **JavaFX** Support*,  that doesn't mean  JRE/JDK. I think the question is off-topic in that case.

Comment: @nullpointer. No, in the [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk9certconfig-3761018.html) there's no longer a row for Solaris x64, only a row for Solaris SPARC. The row is simply completely gone compared to Java 8 situation.

Comment: they just didn't publish it, raise it with Oracle Support, this happened before. The JDK9 list does look sloppy.

Comment: @access_granted. Maybe so, but in that case strange that it is also gone from the list of certified platforms in addition to not being on the download list.

Comment: Two months later the situation is still the same. I can only conclude that Oracle is dropping support for Solaris X64.

Answer (score 2):

Form one of the release note for JDK9, it seems like that it doesn't have ISA specific directory and probably is the reason for the discripency that you notice:-

[Remove Oracle Solaris ISA bin directories and links](http://jdk.java.net/9/release-notes#JDK-8029997)

> On Oracle Solaris, the JDK and JRE no longer have an ISA (Instruction
>   Specific Architecture) bin directory. The *$JAVA_HOME/bin/sparcv9* and
>   *$JAVA_HOME/bin/amd64* directories, and the sym links in the
>   directories, were present in JDK 8 to aid migration after 32-bit
>   support was removed. Scripts or applications that rely on these
>   locations should be updated to use ***$JAVA_HOME/bin***.

Comment: -1. This answer is totally off topic. The question was about which JRE/JDK bundles Oracle publishes. Your answer is about the directory structure *within* such a bundle.

Answer (score 1):

The SmartOS community (ie. Illumos based so a OpenSolaris derivative) is actually working on JDK9/10/11 support in pkgsrc. As far as I know you should be able to use pkgsrc on Oracle Solaris. Jonathan Perkin (of Joyent / pkgsrc) has done excellent work and actually already got JDK 9 and 10 working in pkgsrc (JDK 11 is still WIP):

- https://github.com/joyent/pkgsrc-joyent/tree/master/openjdk9
- https://github.com/joyent/pkgsrc-joyent/tree/master/openjdk10
- https://github.com/joyent/pkgsrc-joyent/tree/master/openjdk11

Join the SmartOS user discussion mailing list in case your interested.

**EDIT 26-07-2019:**

There are also builds of OpenJDK in tarballs available here: http://pkgs.tribblix.org/openjdk/ . As far as I can tell these can be used on all Solaris and Illumos installs.

Comment: I don't wan't to diss this effort but does it provide JDK in an archive format? (zip or tgz) ?   Long gone are the days where you would deploy a Java application and then *hope* the host has a compatible JDK. Today you would either deploy a Java app with a bundled private JDK (hence the need for an archive format for the JDK) or you would deploy to some cloud solution (e.g. Cloud Foundry or similar) where you simply state your JDK requirement. Still, I found your answer useful in the context. Upvoted.

Comment: @peterh I can relate. Easiest would be to install pkgsrc (https://www.pkgsrc.org/) which would allow you to install it with a simple `pkgin install openjdk11`. Using pkgsrc also gives you a whole bunch of other pre-build software. Another way is I think after the whole thing builds it wouldn't be that hard to start working with the people of Adopt OpenJDK to create a x86_64 Solaris tarball and distribute that. Even more interesting would be to see if OpenJDK is interested in accepting patches for Illumos / Solaris x86_64 to make it build with GCC instead of Su...errr Oracle Studio.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no Java 9 for Solaris x64. See MOS Doc ID 2325957.1 for details and explanation.

But you can definitely build and use OpenJDK9.

Comment: Link, please.  (I hope you are not referring to a non-public document??)